# What can I do when I have no output from python function?

Tags: python, function, output

I use this function in python to check a number is even or odd. But it has no output. What is the problem. I want to use this function in another code . But with no output i can't. The function is:

```
def IsEven(n):
    if n%2==0:
        return (True ) 
    else:
        return(False )
IsEven (100)
IsEven (15)
```

And i have no output.

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you need to print the result that returns from the `IsEven` function like below this or accept the returned result to a variable for further use like `result = IsEven(15)`

```
def IsEven(n):
    if n%2==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(IsEven(100))
result = IsEven(15)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i want use this function in a code that print even numbers in range of numbers. So this function can be used in a for loop that in any loop check is the number even or not?! So the output of this function is better to be a logical data.